# How to make cell transparent on selection

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom UITableView with its clearColor background. I'm setting the cell's backgroundView to a transparent UIImageView and setting the background image view's backgroundColor to `[UIColor clearColor]`. I'm also setting the cell's backgroundColor to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

I want to make `cell.backgroundview` as transparent on selection. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can explicitly set a selectedBackgroundView property of the cell with a semitransparent or transparent content (UIimageview) so that i will not become opaque on selection

Comment: Thanks..its working using cell.selectedBackgroundView=(transparent imageview)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwcBdCUZNWs 
i think thats what u r asking for just make the selectedView transparent from the UI properties

Answer (score 0):

In your Cell creation :

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your transparent UIImage"];
```

or:

```
 UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
 v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
```